# Responsive Image Background Quality Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a header that changes size when a user scrolls past a certain point via JavaScript.

When a user scrolls beyond `50px`, the class `.smaller` is added to the header, which affects the child elements, including the logo.

However, when the logo DIV element is resized, the quality of the image seems to change; the edges seem much more jagged and sharper.

This is how it looks normally:

[image]

And scrolled:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
div#header div.logo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:contain;
    float:left;
    padding:0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
}

div#header.smaller div.logo {
    width:262px;
    height:40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
window.onload = init();

function init() {
    //header resize on scroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 50,
            header = document.querySelector("#header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Why is there such a noticeable change in image quality, and how can this be avoided?

Comment: The best way is to resize your image using Photoshop (for example !) and to load the resized image in the `.smaller` class. You have quality issues because the navigator resize your image on the fly, and the original ratio is not respected.

Comment: You should replace your `logo.png` file with SVG.

Comment: @VincentDecaux there is the transition that also affects the resize - if I swap out image sizes, the transition will no longer work as the image will instantly be replaced by it's smaller sibling.

Comment: @w3debugger why will this make a difference?

Comment: True you will loose your transition effect, but firstly you can respect the original ratio. Remove the height property in smaller class.

Comment: The image got blurry when navigator resize your image on the fly. SVG image will not blur your logo.
e.g. http://virtuehost.net/clients/go2markets/ check this site and try to resize this logo.

Comment: @VincentDecaux removing the `height` property doesn't change the issue - the image is still resizing because of the `width` property and the quality still lags

Comment: when you export the logo, there is an option of 'Antialiasing`, have you enabled that?

Comment: @RohitKumar unfortunately I don't have the source file for `logo.png`, it was sent to me by the client

Comment: have you viewed it in different browsers, what was the result?

Comment: @w3debugger your solution worked perfectly - SVG all the way. Post it as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image got blurry when navigator resize your image on the fly. SVG image will not blur your logo. 
e.g. virtuehost.net/clients/go2markets check this site and try to resize this logo.